# Realm append data to a type List<t>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to go through data and save it in my model, however whatever i do i keep getting the following error: `Can't mutate a persisted array outside of a write transaction.`. What am i doing wrong? i'm appending each match to the league however it does not seem to work?

**realm model**

```
class League: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String? = ""
    var matches = List<Match>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Match: Object {
    dynamic var matchId: Int = 0
    dynamic var date: NSDate?
    dynamic var homeName: String? = ""
    dynamic var awayName: String? = ""
    dynamic var awayScore: Int = 0
    dynamic var homeScore: Int = 0
    dynamic var leagueName: String? = ""
    dynamic var homeLogo: NSData?
    dynamic var awayLogo: NSData?
}
```

**Code**

```
    for (_, item) in result {
        if let leagueId = item["league"].int,
            let leagueName = item["name"].string,
            let allMatches = item["matches"].array {
                let league = League()
                league.name = leagueName
                league.id = leagueId

                for match in allMatches {
                    if let matchId = match["matchId"].int,
                        let tournament = match["tournament"].string,
                        let homeTeam = match["homeName"].string,
                        let awayTeam = match["awayName"].string,
                        let homeScore = match["homeScore"].int,
                        let awayScore = match["awayScore"].int,
                        let homeLogo = match["homeLogo"].string,
                        let awayLogo = match["awayLogo"].string,
                        let date = match["date"].string {
                            if let awayLogoUrl = NSURL(string: awayLogo),
                                let homeLogoUrl = NSURL(string: homeLogo) {
                                    if let awayLogoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: awayLogoUrl),
                                        let homeLogoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: homeLogoUrl) {
                                            let matchObject = Match()
                                            matchObject.matchId = matchId
                                            matchObject.leagueName = tournament
                                            matchObject.homeName = homeTeam
                                            matchObject.awayName = awayTeam
                                            matchObject.homeScore = homeScore
                                            matchObject.awayScore = awayScore
                                            matchObject.homeLogo = homeLogoData
                                            matchObject.awayLogo = awayLogoData

                                            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
                                            formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")
                                            matchObject.date = formatter.dateFromString(date)!

                                            league.matches.append(matchObject)
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                    print(league)

                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(league, update: true)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplifying your code to show only the general structure helps to reveal the issue:

```
let league = League()
league.name = leagueName
league.id = leagueId

for match in allMatches {
    if … {
        let matchObject = Match()
        …

        league.matches.append(matchObject)
    }

    print(league)

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(league, update: true)
    }
}
```

This is the sequence of events: You start by creating a standalone, unpersisted `League` instance, `league`. For each match, you create a standalone, unpersisted `Match` instance and append it to `league.matches`. You then create a write transaction, and save `league` to the Realm. From this point, `league` is no longer standalone, and may only be modified within a write transaction. On the next iteration of the loop you create another `Match` instance and attempt to append it to `league.matches`. This throws since `league` is persisted and we're not in a write transaction.

One solution here would be to restructure the code so you only save `league` to the Realm once, like so:

```
let league = League()
league.name = leagueName
league.id = leagueId

for match in allMatches {
    if … {
        let matchObject = Match()
        …

        league.matches.append(matchObject)
    }
}

print(league)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(league, update: true)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The post above is wrong, you can't mutate a List of a realm model outside of a write block.

the correct way would be:

```
try! realm.write {
    league.matches.append(matchObject)
    realm.add(league, update: true)
}
```

At least this is the usual way with Realm Version 0.98