# Save array values in a Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Im using Realm DB for saving offline data in iOS. Can I save array values directly to the Realm DB without using for loop?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for loop?

Comment: can you show some code how you are saving the data in Realm?

Answer (score 1):

By default, you *cannot* do this, Realm uses [Lists](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html):

> List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many
> relationships.
>
> Like Swift’s Array, List is a generic type that is parameterized on
> the type of Object it stores.

```
class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var name = "Default"
}

func listToArray() {
    let objectsArray = [MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject()]
    var objectsRealmList = List<MyObject>()
    
    objectsRealmList = objectsArray
}
```

If you are thinking of something like `objectsRealmList = objectsArray` that would be illegal you cannot assign an array to a realm list.

Thus, as the same logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33744690/5501940), you would need to iterate through `objectsArray`:

```
func arrayToList() {
    let objectsArray = [MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject()]
    let objectsRealmList = List<MyObject>()

    // this one is illegal
    //objectsRealmList = objectsArray
    
    for object in objectsArray {
        objectsRealmList.append(object)
    }
    
    // storing the data...
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(objectsRealmList)
    }
}
```

*Usually, the list would be as a property of an Object, you should add the object itself.*